# How to fix Azure DevOps org error "This user can not be invited" while adding user?

Tags: azure-devops

Background:

- A user has created Azure DevOps Service Org and is now an owner of
  that org.
- owner has setup security policies to allow "Guest Access" for Azure
  DevOps Service organization.
- owner is trying to add user with basic access.
- There is no Billing setup with Azure subscription.

However, the Owner is unable to add new user. And receiving below error:

> This user can not be invited because the domain of user's email
> address is a verified domain of this directory.

So how to fix this and what is the solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the added user is using a verified domain email address, for example, user1@abc.com. He cannot be added to AAD as Guest role. The "Guest Access" Policy does not apply for this scenario.

You need to create a new user using this email address "user1@abc.com" in your AAD first. He will have a Member role in AAD at this step. And then invite this user to Azure DevOps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But for the first 5 users you do not need to attach AAD to Azure DevOps service as per my knowldge. So which AAD are you referring to when I am just creating the ADO org out of no where and not connecting it with any Azure Tenant?